# How can I wildcard search on Google without a space? Ex. `google*` => to match only `googled`, not `google foo`

Tags: google-search, google-search-console, google-search-platform

How can I search Google *only* for *connected* wildcard results?

For example:

```
1. "google*" https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22google*%22
```

Matches: `Google Account`, `Google Voice`, etc.

How do I skip those results and *only* include results like: `google1`, `googled`, `googlefoo`?

Another example:

```
2. "*0 dollars" https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22*0%20dollars%22
```

Matches: `What can I buy for 0 dollars?` instead of *only* results like `10 dollars` or even (though less desirable) `(0 dollars`?

Comment: See https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19673/is-there-a-way-to-search-in-google-using-regular-expressions-regex for related discussion